# to do a simple response in app.js upon html form submit

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, mongodb, forms

Thank you all of you in advance! Really ><

There is a form inside a DIV to compose an email. Users enter recipient, title and content and click submit. The form can submit.

in html:

```
<form id='formid' name='compose1' action='/composemail' method='post'>
    New Message
    <p>To: <input type='textbox' name='recipient'></p>
    <p>Subject: <input type='textbox' name='title'></p>
    <p><input type='textarea' name='content' class='textarea'></p>
    <input type='hidden' id='formTime' name='time' value='20:00:01 Wed Nov 06 2019'>
    <input type='submit' id="formSubmit" value='Send'>
</form>
```

After clicking submit, the data is inserted into a mongo database. Data can be successfully added.
in app.js:

```
app.post('/composemail', express.urlencoded({extended:true}), function(req,res) {
    var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.get('emailList');
    var sender = "abc@mail.com";
    var recipient = req.body.recipient;
    var title = req.body.title;
    var time = req.body.time;
    var content = req.body.content;
    var mailbox = "Sent";
    var newmail = {'sender':sender,'recipient':recipient,'title':title,'time':time,'content':content,'mailbox':mailbox};
    collection.insert(newmail, function(err,result) {
        if (err === null) {
            console.log("Successfully added!");
            res.json({success: true}); // <-problem here
        } else res.send(err);
    })
})
```

in another file call script.js, there is a function call show

```
function show() {
    //basically a XMLHttpRequest to receive the email list from the database
}
```

The problem is the response after the data is inserted. I want it to stay at the same page and run show() function in script.js after the form is submitted.

I search on the internet and find this may be useful: res.json({success: true});
but I want to avoid using ajax as it is really complicated...
can I implement when success is true, then run show() function in the simple form in html? i have tried:

```
<form id='formid' name='compose1' action='/composemail' method='post' success='show(variable)'>
```

it seems not working... or if I really have to use ajax, how can i do it? i really have no idea about it...

Thank you very much!

Comment: Really not sure what the question is. Perhaps attempt to show an example of what you expect to happen, even if the code itself is not working.

Comment: I tried to edit it, hopefully you can understand. Thank you! ><

Comment: Wrap your request with that `show` function, return Promise and after request is succeeded do what you want.